# How to make a typescript object with fields sorted by order of insertion

Tags: typescript, learndash

I am at odd situation where I need to make an object with unknown properties and these properties need to be in order of insertion. It's needed like this because I'm sending it to a server that I don't control. ex:

```
{
  "sfwd-lessons": {
    "256": {
      "sfwd-topic": {
        "270": {
          "sfwd-quiz": []
        }
      },
      "sfwd-quiz": {
        "289": []
      }
    },
    "255": {
      "sfwd-topic": [],
      "sfwd-quiz": []
    }
  },
  "sfwd-quiz": []
}
```

When I create the object and try to send it the entries "256" and "255" switch places since objects will sort their properties automatically.
I tried using several techniques like:

- Record<string,any> //that's what I used initially to create my object
- Map //When I tried to put the Map inside an object it became empty
- Making my own type //Same result as Record<string,any>

I'm lost here.

Comment: "typescript will sort their properties automatically" That doesn't seem to be the case... https://tsplay.dev/m0zJaw

Comment: @Joseph.Botros, the order of object keys is not fully under our control as developers. In particular, number-like keys can be put into numeric order. It's not typescript that's doing this, but javascript. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order

Comment: @NicholasTower okay I removed the part of typescript, now how do I solve my problem?

Comment: I'm afraid i don't know. This is not something that objects are meant to do.

Comment: Sounds like a broken server if the order of the keys is important to them.

Comment: If your use case is "sending it to a server" then would you accept something that stores numeric keys with a special prefix and then outputs the string in the desired order, maybe like [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w6pD6m)? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Since your concern about the order being maintained is related to communicating with a server API. Presumably this means you're encoding your data structure as a string. So as a workaround that gives you full control of the order, you can simply do the encoding yourself, manually. Instead of relying on `JSON.stringify` of some object, you can encode it yourself.

In JavaScript, `Map` objects maintain the insertion order of keys, so you can encode your data as follows:

```
const data = new Map()
data.set("sfwd-lessons", new Map())
// ...
```

And then you can encode it into a JSON string by assembling a string from the contents of the map. Since it preserves insertion order, you can simply loop over it.